# When do you consider the writing of a theoretical framework to be complete?

Tags: writing, theory, research-proposal

As I am writing the proposal for my thesis, I am finding a lot of works to include in my theoretical framework with some items that take the spotlight because they are tied into my methodology. I'm doing an exploratory case study so many options are open and my topic potentially intersects a few fields. I am wondering, when does it become too much? When is it sufficient?

How should I decide what to include and what to skip when writing my theoretical framework? (in an exploratory study)

Comment: This will obviously depend on your field of study, but I'd expect it to also depend on the specific topic within that field, the conventions in your university and your department, and even the preferences of individual professors.  I'd say that only your adviser can give you a definite answer; all you can get from strangers like me would be wild guesses.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Hmm, would it be a better question if I asked what should form a theoretical framework, or what is a theoretical framework? It doesn't seem like it was asked before and might be helpful for me regardless.

Comment: I think that the questions suggested in your comment  will still get only wild guesses as answers. But of course you can try it out and see what happens.

Comment: That section of your document will help the reader understand your contribution, and it will show your committee that you know what you're talking about.  Try to accomplish that in as little space and time as you can.

Answer (score 1):

Short version: Ask your advisor.

---

Long answer:

It's hard to answer that, as we neither know your field nor your university. Furthermore, a proposal is not a complete thesis, so there might be also differences because of that, there might even be regulations at your university that a proposal can only have some fixed number of pages.

As you are looking for advice, here is one:
Make a list of all the topics you deem relevant. Write down which paper you want to quote, write down who you want to mention, etc. Don't turn it into a full text yet, only put short headwords. Then, take your list and ask around at your university. A good starting point would be your (potential) advisor, as he should know both the regulations at the university and the field you are working on. If you don't have one yet, everyone with experience in this two points (other professors, PhD students, etc.) will do - you might even use this to look around for an advisor in this case.

As professors are often busy, your best chance should be to write a short mail describing your problem and asking for an appointment to discuss the list in person. Thus, your email won't land in a "to long, handle later" folder, you will already establish a personal contact, etc.